# Estimate fatigue life parameters in R

Tags: r, distributions

I have project where I'm given a set of times between a certain event and then I have to estimate the parameters for the ditribution function with the best fit using R, similar to what [EasyFit](http://www.mathwave.com/products/easyfit.html) does.

Unfortunately, I'm fairly new to R and statistics in general so I'm having a hard time getting off the ground. I'm attempting to use the fitdistr package but I can't figure out if it supports fatigue life functions. Is there another package I'm missing that might serve better?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: When you say 'fatigue life distributions' do you mean [the Birnbaum–Saunders distribution (also known as the fatigue life distribution)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_life_distribution)? Or something more general?

Comment: Birnbaum-Saunders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching http://www.rseek.org for "Birnbaum-Saunders" finds a package [gbs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbs/gbs.pdf) for *Generalized* Birnbaum-Saunders Distributions. It includes a function `mlebs()` to fit the parameters of classic (i.e. ungeneralized) Birnbaum-Saunders distribution by maximum likelihood estimation.